# Problem with Gazebo model data base

Tags: ros, gazebo, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Hydro version in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The time I am launching the Gazebo Simulator with Summit_XL with cube as an obstacle in the terminal it is showing "Unable to get model name[http://gazebosim.org/models/wooden_peg_board]". I have done the ROS update but still it is the same. Is there currently any problem with the Gazebo Simulator data base or I am missing any update operation for the Gazebo Simulator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206565/problem-with-gazebo-model-data-base/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2015-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file you are looking for is at http://old.gazebosim.org/models/wooden_peg_board/
This looks like a mismatch between versions of gazebo and ros.
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install&ver=3.0

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0